# How to define a derived class in c++?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, derived-class

I learnt Walter Savitch's Absolute C++ (5th ed.) about 2 years ago. The way to declare a derived class in this book is that

```
class ChildClass:Public ParentClass{...}
```

where the parent class is something like

```
class ParentClass
{Public:
 double getVariable() const;
...}
```

This book also says that if I do not want to change the definition of a member function of the parent class when I declare a derived class, I do not have to rewrite it in the derived class declaration. For example, if I do not want to change the definition of `double ParentClass::getVariable() const`, which assesses a member variable of `ParentClass`, I do not have to explicitly write it down again in the declaration of the derived class `ChildClass`.

Recently, I wanted to work out a project, and found something that changed over the years. Firstly, the declaration of the derived class should look like

```
class ChildClass:ParentClass{...}
```

You should not insert `Public` in front of `ParentClass`, otherwise, the compiler complains. Secondly, I cannot access the function `double ParentClass::getVariable() const` in the main program by the following code

```
childInstance.getVariable()
```

where `childInstance` is an instance of `ChildClass`.

These are the two things changing I found. Would you please tell me how to define a derived class in the correct way? Thank you!

By the way, the complier I am using is gcc 5.4.0 on Cygwin.

Comment: You probably should prefer one of [these books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242) and throw what you have into the bin.

Comment: `Public` is something very different from `public`. One is wrong and the other is correct.

Comment: And you should note that c++ is a case sensitive language. `Public` isn't the same as `public`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Public` is nothing special in C++.

You should write `public`.

Even the syntax highlighting should tell you the error.

See this example:

```cpp
if else for while public
Am Tree Hat House Public
                  ^~~~~~
```

After you've adapted to the correct keyword, there should be no more problems. By default things about `class` are `private`.